# What is sprintf_s analog of sprintf(newpath, "%s%s",...)?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm using `sprintf(newpath, "%s%s", cCurrentPath, "\\init.scm");` to add \init.scm to current dir path but there is the usual warning:

> `warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe.
>   Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.`

`Sprintf_s` doesn't support such "%s%s" string sum. How can I do it using `sprintf_s`?

Comment: "Sprintf_s doesn't support such "%s%s" string sum"? Are you sure? (BTW, it's usually called concatenation when you talk about strings, not "sum".)

Comment: yes it shows warning C4024: 'sprintf_s' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2 and fails on run

Comment: I don't think so because sprintf works just fine.

Comment: It's a bug in your code. As ugoren points out, both functions work the same way. You're passing incorrect arguments.

Comment: You're also missing a backslash in `"\init.scm"` - you need `\\` for a single backslash.

Comment: But sprintf works without second parameter (size).

Comment: Note that the _s functions may be deprecated in future C standards as they were controversial and many vendors refused to implement them (except MS, who proposed them, though didn't update their implementation to comply with the standard).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`sprintf_s` is basically the same as `sprintf`, but it gets another parameter:

```
sprintf_s(newpath, sizeof(newpath), "%s%s", cCurrentPath, "\\init.scm");
```

Note - if `newpath` is a normal character array, `sizeof(newpath)` works. If it's a pointer or an array passed as an argument, you may need a different way to get the size.
You can also use `snprintf` for the same purpose in a non-MS environment (though it works differently).

Comment: But %s%s is sum of 2 strings which is going to newpath. How to make it?

Comment: The _s functions are built for safety, so you don't attempt to overwrite non-allocated memory. For this reason, the 2nd param has to be the size of the allocated memory for the 1st param) It has nothing to so with the following params, it ensures that there will be no memory access violation if the actual text is longer than expected.

Comment: Sorry, but I omitted the format string. Fixed now, you use it just as I wrote.

Comment: Might want to use `__countof(newpath)` to avoid future mistakes (e.g. when converting code to use `swprintf_s`). Or, if using C++, simply use `sprintf_s(newpath, "%s%s", cCurrentPath, "\\init.scm");` (assuming that the buffer is local).