# fprintf stderr segfaults in its own thread, works in main

Tags: c, windows, printf

I built a little prototype test program do deal with windows performance counters and everything seems to work ok.  I moved it into my dll, which my main program loads, and there are some fprintf(stderr, "sometext") which are causing an access violation.

I look into this on SO and didnt find any satisfactory answer.  I know it works fine when it runs in the main thread.  I assume its from the TIME_CRITICAL thread i spawn to do the performance counter polling.

1. What is the cause of this access violation?  It says "unhandled exception at 0x7deadbeef in main.exe 0xC00000005.  Access violation reading from 0xFbeefdead".
2. What is the appropriate way to print to stderr from a separate thread?

It seems to be kind of "random" since i have printfs at the start of the polling function that print fine.  Towards the bottom they throw the access violation.  Why do some printf/fprintf(stderr) work fine while other fail?

*EDIT*
I create the thread with 0 as the stack size parameter, which should default to the default stack size.  I suspect im blowing my stack in this thread, does anyone have any insight into this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread

Comment: It would help to mention which compiler you are using

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi guys, Im using VC++ 2008 and i cant post any code unfortunately.  If there is not a common issue here i suspect i have a bug elsewhere, i removed the printfs and it works fine though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i suspected the symptom was an issue with something unrelated to the printf/fprintfs.  At an early point in the program i sprintf many strings, which was part of a struct.  Instead of passing the size of the struct member to sprintf i passed the size of the whole struct, which caused me to overflow a buffer and mangle god knows how much memory.  When this was in one main thread it didnt overflow enough to blow my stack and cause a segfault, but it did still write past the buffer.

Since there were less function calls in the stand alone program the chance of over-writing the stack pointer was zero, when brought into the real program/dll the call hierarchy becomes non-trivial and a massive buffer overflow is sure to overwrite the stack pointer, so printf from a thread with address range 0x7ABCDEF tries to jump to a return address of 0xF1234567 causing the access voilation.

I posted my story here for future readers.  Here is some sprintf_s resource if the next guy has a similar issue:
[What is sprintf_s analog of sprintf(newpath, "%s%s",...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906274/what-is-sprintf-s-analog-of-sprintfnewpath-ss)